# Autofill from last row to adjacent column's last row

Tags: excel, vba, autofill

I have three columns of data in an Excel sheet for which I add more rows of data each day. The aim is to copy the last row data of columns A and B until the last row of C, which is always some rows below. I managed to do part of that in the following code:

```
Range("A2").End(XlDirection.xlDown).Select
Selection.Resize(numRows + 1, numColumns + 2).AutoFill Destination:=Range("A11:B20"), Type:=xlFillCopy
Range("A11:B20").Select
```

The problem is with the range ("A11:B20"). I need it to be dynamic as the number of used rows will increase every day. Is there a way to make it dynamic?

Comment: Can yu add some more information, what language do you use, what part of A11:B20 should change

Comment: Thank you for help. It's VBA and Excel. I need to copy the last cells of columns A and B down until the last row of C, that is always further down than A and B. 

An example: 

data in A2:B10 and data in C2:C20, copy A10:B10 and paste values to A11:B20.